# Highcharts with ajax / json

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

This isn't really a problem with Highcharts but rather more with the javascript function that passes the data. Now first off , my java skills are pretty basic .. well , actually pretty damn bad to be honest. So laughing at my code would be the equivalent of laughing at handy capped people :)

Anyway, the idea is pretty simple , I'm basically feeding a highcharts graphs with network traffic which is gathered by a PHP script via a SNNP call.

The data is then encoded with json_encode and the output looks like this: [1464786728000,13850896]
The first value is the current time and the second value is the traffic measured in Octets. I've included the PHP script below.

Now all of this works pretty well , the data gets collected and the graphs plots in real time with no issues. The problem comes in where I have to pass the current value back into the javascript function so I can deduct is as the previous value from the current value so I'm left with the difference between intervals. I then need to multiply that value by 8 ... since I'm converting the Octets into bits and then divide it by the poll interval. All this should be rather simple but for some reason I'm unable to read the previous variable back when I pass it.

I really hope I'm even making sense here ;)

```
function requestData(previous) {
var poll     = 1000;

$.ajax({
   url: 'grabetherTraffic.php?canopyIP=<? echo $canopyIP; ?>',
   success: function(point) {
      var series = chart.series[0] ;
      shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is 

      // Little Formula to figure out that the current thoughput on the interface is.  
      // I need to basically deduct the previous data from the current data when the
      // timeout expires and the function fires again.
   var bps = (series - previous) * 8 / poll;

      // Plot bps.. 
   bps.addPoint(point, true, shift);            

      // Here's my attempt to pass the current data back to the function when it fires again. 
   setTimeout(function () { requestData(series); }, poll);

        },
        cache: false
    });
}
```

PHP Script...

```
<?php 
// Set the JSON header
include 'snmpiods.php';
$canopyIP = $_REQUEST['canopyIP'];
$x = time() * 1000;

$gatherRX = getSNMPDATA("$canopyIP","1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10");
list($null, $gatherRX) = split(" ", $gatherRX, 2);
settype($gatherRX, "integer"); 

header("Content-type: text/json");
$ret = array($x, $gatherRX);
echo json_encode($ret);

?>
```

Comment: In short, you want to get last point in the data, when new one arrives? Something like this should do the trick: `var prev = series.data[series.data.length - 1], bps = (point[0] - prev.x) * 8 / poll`.

Comment: Hi Pawel, thanks for taking the time but I was wondering whether you'll be able to give me a short explanation of what's happening in your code and how do I actually use the object to plot the next point? 

Also , what's the function of the .x in your variable prev.x ? I'm getting the following error when I use it like that.  

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined$.ajax.success @ plotband.php?canopyIP=172.100.1.2:41e.resolveWith @ jquery.min.js:2w @ jquery.min.js:4d @ jquery.min.js:4"

Comment: Sure, first I try to get last point, and store it a variable: `var prev = series.data[series.data.length - 1];`. `x` comes from Highcharts API, see [Point class](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point) - you can get more info about the point, like `y`, `name` etc. properties. And regarding the problem - maybe for the first point you have nothing to compare with? When adding first point, then there's no previous point? Something like `if (prev) { var bps = .... ; series.addPoint( [point[0], bps], true, shift); } else { series.addPoint( point, true )` should do the thing.

Comment: Wow thanks for that ... I'm starting to see some light at the end of the tunnel :).